# Javascript inject CSS into Swift WebView

Tags: javascript, css, swift

I'm trying to load a page on xCode and then override it's styling with another file. I've tested this out manually in Chrome and 2 sections of the page should turn bright red, but they don't in my XCode project. Any ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var urlPath = "http://grappul.com"

@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    loadAddress()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadAddress(){
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:urlPath)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    println("got the page!")
    webViewDidFinishLoad(webView)
}

func webViewDidFinishLoad(website: UIWebView){
    var jsscript = "var script = document.createElement('link');
    script.type = 'text/css'; 
    script.rel = 'stylesheet'; 
    script.href = 'http://www.grappul.com/snapkin/restyle.css';
    document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"
    println("got the css!")
    website.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString(jsscript)
}
```

Thanks a ton guys!

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView seems not to have a big JavaScript interface to look for error reporting, but you should take a look at the Safari Web inspector and its ability to monitor any UIWebView app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

However there seems to be a bit of extra work necessary to get it working with any iOS app (see Get Oriented: Webkit-based apps)